# Show the set $\{x \in \Bbb Q : x>0, 2<x^2<3\}$ is open and closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Show that in the metric space $\Bbb Q$, with the usual metric (given by the absolute value), the set $$S=\{x \in\Bbb Q : x>0, 2<x^2<3\}$$ is both open and closed.

**My attempt:**

I need to show that no limit point of the set $S$ lies outside of $S$ and I also need to show that every point of this set is an interior point.
How should I proceed?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

$S=(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)\cap\mathbb Q=[\sqrt2,\sqrt3]\cap\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$S=(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) \cap \mathbb Q=[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}] \cap \mathbb Q.$$
So $S$ is the intersection of an open set in $\mathbb R$ with $\mathbb Q$. That are precisely the open sets of $\mathbb Q$.

To prove that let $A\subset \mathbb R$ be open in $\mathbb R$. Then for every $x\in A$ there is an $r>0$ with $B_r(x)\subset A$. So we have

$$B_r^{\mathbb Q}(x) = B_r(x) \cap \mathbb Q \subset A \cap \mathbb Q.$$

Hence $A\cap\mathbb Q$ is open in $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers take for granted that the topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ is the subspace topology of $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$, and that $(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)$ (resp. $[\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3]$) is open (resp. closed) in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $x$ be a limit point of $S$, i.e. there is a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset S$ such that $\lim x_n = x$. Then $\forall n, x_n > 0 \implies x \ge 0$, and $\forall n, 2 < x_n^2 < 3 \implies 2 \le x^2 \le 3$. Both $x \ge 0$ and $x^2 \ge 2$, therefore $x > 0$. And since there is no rational number such that either $x^2 = 2$ or $x^2 = 3$, it follows that actually $2 < x^2 < 3$, therefore $x \in S$. So all the accumulation points of $S$ are in $S$.

Similarly, suppose $x = \lim x_n$ with $\forall n, x_n \not\in S$. If $x \le 0$ we're done. Otherwise ($x > 0$), for big enough $n$, $x_n > 0$. Assume  that $2 < x^2 < 3$. Then for big enough $n$, $2 < x_n^2 < 3$ too, a contradiction. Therefore $x \not\in S$.

Comment: Seems that $S$ is indeed closed, but unfortunatly I can't see why. In fact, it seems to me that it's not the case. Even if ${x_n}$ is a sequence of rational numbers, its limit may be irrational. In fact, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we can construct a sequence of rational numbers in $S$ which limit is $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ isn't in $S$ while it is a limit point of $S$. Could you please tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: "its limit may be irrational": your mistake is here. I let $x$ be a limit point of $S \subset \mathbb{Q}$. So by definition $x$ is rational, a point of $\mathbb{Q}$. If I give you a space $X$, and a subset $S \subset X$, and tell you $x$ is a limit point of $x$, do you agree that $x \in X$? The fact that there's a bigger space $Y$ containing $X$ has no bearing here. Well, take $X = \mathbb{Q}$ and $S$ as in the question.

Comment: Oh! In the OP's question: "In the metric space $\mathbb{Q}$". Yes yes you're definitively right. Sorry for bothering you. شكرا جزيلا Thank you very much :D

Comment: I don't speak Arabic so I don't know what that last part means, but you're welcome (and it's no problem, you're not bothering me).

Comment: From your name I thought you do. What I wrote is "Thank you very much" (both in Arabic and English).

Comment: Yep, I'm half Moroccan, but sadly I forgot all the Arabic I knew when I was younger :/ Anyway you're welcome.

Comment: Haha as expected ! I'm Moroccan too :D Forgetting a language once abroad in an early age is normal, especially that you're half Moroccan so you were talking Frensh at home.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Recall that the topology on $\Bbb Q$ is the induced topology as a subspace of $\Bbb R$. In a subspace, a set is open if it is the intersection of the subspace with an open set in the ambient space (and analogously for closed sets). If you can show $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}\notin\Bbb Q$, you will be done (why?).

Comment: your hint is correct ,but i dont understand it. where can i read about this concept?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology is a good start

Comment: "your hint is correct ,but i dont understand it." -- very Zen.